# Fraction as power

Tags: fractions

Is there a more elegant way to write a fraction as power?

```
 $a^{ \frac{m}{n} } = \sqrt[n]{a^{m}}$
```

[image]

Comment: This is already **very elegant** :). Welcome to TeX.SE

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is a fraction by a slash symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $a^{ \frac{m}{n} } = \sqrt[n]{a^{m}}$

  $a^{ m/n } = \sqrt[n]{a^{m}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]